# How to bulk rename files by cutting starting at a certain character

Tags: linux, bash

I have music file with crappy file name like this:

```
LetMeBeTheOne[Outtakeb-SideTolongMistyDays[2010DigitalRemaster-1.mp3
TheFoolAndMe[DigitalRemaster.mp3
```

I want to rename the file by cutting starting at the first [ character, which would actually be the real name of the file.

```
LetMeBeTheOne.mp3
TheFoolAndMe.mp3
```

I came up with this but can't figure out how to rewrite the file using this;

```
for file in *.mp3
do str="$file"
echo "${str%%[*}".mp3;
done
```

This will properly write the file names to std out but how can I get it to write the filename to the drive? I know it's something simple but I have hit a wall. I should probably go to bed.  :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
for file in *.mp3
do str="$file"
mv $file "${str%%[*}".mp3;
done
```

Forgot to mv it.  need sleep.